# Powershell Rename PC and Join Domain

Tags: powershell

I have two scripts that work perfectly by themselves.

```
#Rename the PC`enter code here`
$user = "localusername"
$password = "localpassword" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$Credential = New-object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($user,$password)
Rename Computer -Newname "NewComputerName" -LocalCredential $Credential
```

Now that works perfectly and renames the computer without issue.

```
#Join the domain
$domain = "mydomain"
$user = "Domainusername"
$password = "Domainpassword" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$Credential = New-object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($user,$password)
Add-Computer -DomainName DomainName -Credential $Credential
```

That also works perfectly and joins the domain.

However when I try to run them together under a single .bat it joins the domain, but does not rename the PC. I have tried using another command between them, I have tried using the wait or pause function, that hasn't work.

Please let me know if you have any recommendations. I am using Powershell V5

Full batch file

```
#Change password for Administrator
$NewPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "@ccessnw0" –AsPlainText –Force
Set-LocalUser –Name Administrator –Password $NewPassword

#Remove Test account
Remove-LocalUser -Name Test -Verbose

#Set time zone to Eastern
Set-TimeZone -Name "Eastern Standard Time"

#Disable sleep mode and hibernation
powercfg –h off
c:\windows\system32\powercfg.exe -change -monitor-timeout-ac 0
c:\windows\system32\powercfg.exe -change -monitor-timeout-dc 0
c:\windows\system32\powercfg.exe -change -disk-timeout-ac 0
c:\windows\system32\powercfg.exe -change -disk-timeout-dc 0
c:\windows\system32\powercfg.exe -change -standby-timeout-ac 0
c:\windows\system32\powercfg.exe -change -standby-timeout-dc 0
c:\windows\system32\powercfg.exe -change -hibernate-timeout-ac 0
c:\windows\system32\powercfg.exe -change -hibernate-timeout-dc 0

#Enable remote desktop
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal 
Server'-name "fDenyTSConnections" -Value 0
Enable-NetFirewallRule -DisplayGroup "Remote Desktop"

#Rename the PC enter code here
$user = "localusername"
$password = "localpassword" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText - 
Force
$Credential = New-object 
System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($user,$password)
Rename Computer -Newname "NewComputerName" -LocalCredential 
$Credential

#Join the domain
$domain = "mydomain"
$user = "Domainusername"
$password = "Domainpassword" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText - 
Force
$Credential = New-object 
System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($user,$password)
Add-Computer -DomainName DomainName -Credential $Credential
```

Comment: Can you show the batch file?

Comment: Which one is it that you run first?

Comment: I’d rename it, reboot, join domain, reboot

Comment: You forgot a hyphen here `Rename Computer`.,,

Comment: I was thinking about doing that...I was looking into a way to "start and stop" the batch file so that it will reboot and then continue where it left off, reboot, and then continue where it left off...is it possible to do that?

Comment: Towards the end you've got a few parameters (`-Force` x 2, `-LocalCredential`) spread across two lines.  Is that a copy-and-paste artifact?

Comment: Yeah, in my notepad there's only -Force being used in the rename and then once more in the join the domain one. As for the local there's only one in the rename

Comment: Again.. You made a typo with `Rename Computer`. It should be `Rename-Computer`. You missed the hyphen in between. P.S. that is not a batch file, but a PowerShell script.

Comment: May be I have missed something, but why do you rename then add the computer. You can do it in a single command : `Add-Computer -DomainName mydom.adds -Credential $Cred -NewName "NewComputerName" -Restart`

Comment: CFou, can I do that, but without inputting my credentials? Also, I'm sorry if I forgot the hypen Theo, it isn't that way in the actual powershell script, that's just my bad typing showing.

Answer (score -1):

I'm providing a subset (see below) as part of a wider **PowerShell** script I used. The structure (steps) I used was the following. I'm **demonstrating** how **I** updated **remote computers** using **PowerShell**. It may **differ** from your current approach.

1. Build Local Security Structure
2. Build Sever Name Variables
3. Create a New-PowerShell Session To Remote Computer
4. Update NetConnectionProfile, advfirewall, wsman, NetFirewallRule, TS,  RenameComuter
5. Restart Computer
6. Poll Computer For Remote Registry
7. Remove The Remote PowerShell Session
8. Build Domain Security Structure
9. Join Computer To Domain
10. Add Domain Admins Group to Local Admins Group
11. Restart Computer

Line 24 of the script sets 'Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI)', bit the **may** need updating to CMI, as WMI has been deprecated.

```
$server = "servername"
$RequestingServer = $env:COMPUTERNAME
$newServerName = "newServerName"

[STRING] $LocalUser = "Administrator"
[STRING] $LocalPassword = "Password01"
$LocalSecurePassword = $LocalPassword | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$LocalCredentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $LocalUser, $LocalSecurePassword

Write-Host "Line 10"

#Update Windows Firewall Remotely
$LocalSession = New-PSSession -Computername $Server -Credential $LocalCredentials
Invoke-Command -Session $LocalSession -ScriptBlock {

$AddServerName = $Using:RequestingServer
$AddNewServerName = $Using:newServerName
$Acc = $Using:LocalCredentials

    #Update Windows Firewall from Public to Private
    Get-NetConnectionProfile | Set-NetConnectionProfile -NetworkCategory Private
    
    #Update Windows Firewall to allow remote WMI Access
    netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI)" new enable=yes
    
    #Update Trusted Hosts is not domain-joined and therefore must be added to the TrustedHosts list 
    Set-Item wsman:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -Value $AddServerName -Force
    Set-Item wsman:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -Value $AddNewServerName -Force
    
    #Update Windows Firewall to allow RDP
    Enable-NetFirewallRule -DisplayGroup "Remote Desktop"
    
    #Enable RDP : 1 = Disable ; 0 = Enable
    Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server" -Name "fDenyTSConnections" -Value 0
    
    #https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-computer?view=powershell-6
    #For computers that are in a workgroup, run PowerShell console as administrato
    Rename-Computer -ComputerName "$AddServerName" -NewName "$AddNewServerName" -LocalCredential "$Acc" -Restart -Force
}

#Restart Server
#Restart-Computer -ComputerName "$server" -Credential $LocalCredentials -Impersonation 3 -Authentication 6 -Force
Start-Sleep -s 180
#Wait for Server to Restart
Do {(Write-Host "The Old Server $server has been renamed to $newServerName and is restarting"),(Start-Sleep -seconds 60)}
#Until ((Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -ComputerName $Server -Credential $LocalCredentials -Impersonation 3 -Authentication 6 | Where-Object{$_.Name -eq 'RemoteRegistry'}).State -eq 'Running')
Until ((Get-CimInstance -Class "Win32_Service" -ComputerName $newServerName -Credential $LocalCredentials -Impersonation 3 -Authentication 6 | Where-Object{$_.Name -eq 'RemoteRegistry'}).State -eq 'Running')

Write-Host "Line 46"
Get-PSSession | Remove-PSSession

Start-Sleep -s 60
#Exit

do {

    # Load Function to get logonDC fqdn
    Function Get-LogonDC {
        return ([ADSI]'LDAP://RootDSE').dnsHostName
    }
    
    # Load Function to get forest fqdn
    Function Get-ForestRootNC {
        return ([ADSI]'LDAP://RootDSE').rootDomainNamingContext
    }

    # Load Function to get Domain DNS
    Function Get-DNSDomain {
        return $env:USERDNSDOMAIN
    }
    
[STRING]$GetLogonDC = (Get-LogonDC)
[STRING]$GetDNSDomain = (Get-DNSDomain)


#Domain Admin Account 
[STRING]$DomainAccountName = (whoami)
[STRING]$DomainAccountName = $DomainAccountName.Split("\")[1]
[STRING]$DomainAccountPassword = "Password*01"          
$DomainAccountSecurePassword = $DomainAccountPassword | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
#$DomainCredentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $DomainAccountName, $DomainAccountSecurePassword

$dnsdomain = $GetDNSDomain
$domainacc = $DomainAccountName
#$domainpwd = $DomainAccountSecurePassword

#Join Server to Domain
#$comp = Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\cimv2" -Class "Win32_ComputerSystem" -ComputerName "$newServerName" -Credential $LocalCredentials -Impersonation 3 -Authentication 6
$comp = Get-CimInstance -Namespace "root\cimv2" -Class "Win32_ComputerSystem" -ComputerName "$newServerName" -Credential $LocalCredentials -Impersonation 3 -Authentication 6
$comp.joinDomainOrWorkgroup("$dnsdomain","$DomainAccountPassword","$dnsdomain\$domainacc",$null,3)

#Add Domain Admins Group To Server
$ADGroup = ([ADSI]"WinNT://$GetDNSDomain/domain admins").Path
$LocalGroup = ([ADSI]"WinNT://$newServerName/Administrators,group")
($LocalGroup).Add($ADGroup)

#Restart Server
Restart-Computer -ComputerName "$newServerName" -Credential $DomainCredentials -Impersonation 3 -Authentication 6 -Force
                    
Start-Sleep -s 180
```

Comment: It'd be (more) helpful if you explained how the author of the question should apply this to their failing code, instead of dumping a 100-line script where only 3 out of 11 steps relate to what they're trying to do.

Comment: Its very self explanatory.  with note inline.

Comment: No, it doesn't explain at all why the author's script is failing.  "Read through this script and figure it out for yourself" is not a solution.

Comment: Lets agree to disagree on and move forward.

Comment: I appreciate both of your inputs, but if you could spell it out for me, I would most appreciate it. I feel dumb because I feel like the answer is right in front of me, I apologize for any inconvenience!

Comment: Not my intent to make you feel like that. Lets setup a stack overflow discussion channel, and take and take our discussion there. If you update the script I gave you to test on a single remote machine. Lets work through the errors to resolve.